# google drive sdk drive/v2/changes/get 500 error

Tags: google-drive-api

as documented here
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/get

if I GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes/1

{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}

I'm using OAuth 2.0 playground. all my other GET's work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, for which we should have a fix out soon. Sorry about that. You probably don't need to get individual changes though, you could just read the data from the changes feed's `items` field.

Comment: ok thanks, there is another issue with the go client in regards to this but I'll hold of till its released.

Answer (score 0):

Please use OAuth first

```
> Google Drive applications need these three values for authorization:
> 
> Client ID 
> Client secret 
> redirect URIs
```